# How to set ::llvm::DebugFlag when using an LLVM ExecutionEngine instead of clang?

Tags: llvm, julia

The internals of LLVM has diagnostic messages that are conditional on !defined(`NDEBUG`) and a bool flag `::llvm::DebugFlag`.  How do I set `::llvm::DebugFlag` when LLVM is being used in an `ExecutionEngine` that does not parse the command line?

My specific case is the LLVM Execution engine used by the Julia language implementation.

Comment: You may get much better responses on the julia-dev mailing list. I don't know the answer, but of course there are many LLVM experts who aren't on our list and could help.

Comment: See these lines for the ExecutionEngine setup, wherein you could add flags if needed (I suppose it might be useful to add this as a command-line option..)   https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/codegen.cpp#L3493-L3499

Comment: I found that `llvm-3.3/docs/ProgrammersManual.rst` suggests setting the flag directly within GDB using `set DebugFlag=1`.